# Jump command in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, goto

I'm working with the m-file editor of MATLAB and I need to jump from one line to another.
If I need to jump from inside a `For`...`end`, I can't use the usual "while"
technique.
Is there anyway to jump from a line to another, like `goto` in C?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no goto statement in Matlab. But you can almost always avoid goto by restructuring your program.

Comment: There *is* a user-implemented goto statement; you can find it on the [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26949-matlab-goto-statement)

Answer (score 19):

There is no `goto` statement in MATLAB, but there are a few other commands for use with loops that may help you:

- [`continue`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/continue.html): This statement will skip the remaining commands in a for or while loop and move on to the next iteration.
- [`break`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html): This statement will terminate execution of a for or while loop.

Comment: +1; but actually, there *is* a [goto statement in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26949-matlab-goto-statement) :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis For a second I actually thought there is. It's not an actual `goto`, but in most cases it mimics the behavior quite well :)

Answer (score 9):

There is no goto in matlab. However, this does not say you cannot structure your code to use an {if, else, elseif, end} structural form for your code. Or use a {switch, case, end} form. Or call a function (or subfunction or nested function) to solve your problem. Or use a continue/break to structure your code. One can always solve these problems using one of the existing forms of flow control available.

The use of functions can improve your code in other ways, often by making it more modular, and therefore easier to debug and write.

Answer (score 0):

that solves the problem easily:

```
caseno = input('input your case no');

switch (caseno)
     case 1
          disp('this first section will run');
     case 2
          disp('this second section will run');
     otherwise
          disp('wrong case no');
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for j = 1: 1: 24
  % LABEL start
a = a + j;
if a > 10
goto('start') % If condition satisfied goto label start
return
else
  a = a + 1;
end
end
```

Comment: I get the error `Undefined function or variable 'goto'.` using Matlab 2016b.