# Program an iteration which will be stopped when the mentioned circumstance is met

Tags: matlab

Hi everyone I have encountered a problem in writing a programming code for the algorithm as shown below

This program is going to be terminated when the approximate error which is defined as (current approximation-previous approximation)/current approximation is less than 0.01. It can be simplified as (f(xr)i+1 - f(xr)i)/f(xr)i+1. Below are the code that I have written and I would really like to know how can I program an iteration which will be stopped when the mentioned circumstance is met.

```
xl = input('Enter lower limit : ');

xu = input('Enter upper limit : ');

xr = (xl+xu)/2;

R = 3; V = 30;

fl = (pi*R*xl^2)-(pi*(xl^3)/3)-V;    % between is there anyway can call these functions 

fu = (pi*R*xu^2)-(pi*(xu^3)/3)-V;      other than typing 3 times

fh = (pi*R*xr^2)-(pi*(xr^3)/3)-V;


while relative error is less than 0.01 then display value of xr

if fl*fu<0

    xu = xr;


elseif fl*fu>0

    xl = xr;


end

end
```

Comment: You forgot to implement Step 3(c).  You also didn't "return to step 2" in steps 3(a) and 3(b) as the instructions state.

Comment: hmm..that one I think it's just required to add a if statement after all..but the problem that I encounter now is about the iteration and loop condition..thank you for reminding yea..by the way could u help me out in solving this..I will be really really appreciate it.thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the code now that I could run it.  I tested it with f(x)=x^2-2.  It converges to 1.4141 in 6 iterations.  I suggest you compare that code with what you had to understand what was not working for you before.  This will be a good learning experience.

```
>> example(1,2);
Crossing found after 6 iterations: 1.414062
```

where example.m is the following:

```
function xr = root(xl,xu)

MAX_NUMBER_ITERATIONS = 1000;
MAX_DELTA=.01;

numberIterations=0;
xr_old=xu;
xr = (xl+xu)/2;

while ((numberIterations<MAX_NUMBER_ITERATIONS) & (abs(xr_old-xr)>=MAX_DELTA))
    numberIterations=numberIterations+1;
    xr_old = xr;;

    product=f(xl)*f(xr);
    if product<0
        xu = xr;
        xr = (xl+xu)/2;
        continue;  
    elseif product>0
        xl = xr;
        xr = (xl+xu)/2;
        continue;
    else
        break;
    end
end
fprintf('Crossing found after %d iterations: %f\n',numberIterations,xr)

end


function y = f(x)
y=x^2-2;
end
```

Comment: Hmm but how about I am going to stop the program when the relative error is less than 0.01, which is when (current xr-previous xr)/current xr <0.01. This would be the main problem that troubling me. @user91208

Comment: hmm but the problem is I dono how to define the previous xr and the current xr in matlab

Comment: @RobertHarvey could you give me a help

Comment: @green: The condition in the `while` must keep it looping until your exit condition is met.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: yep..but the critical problem for now is I wanted to write something like while abs((current xr-previous xr)/current xr)<0.01
but I just really don't know how to program it in matlab, could you possibly look through the above code and give me some ideas or perhaps you could edit the code above..really thanks a lot

Comment: Is this a problem that converges on a result where the error is below 0.01?  If that's the case, you're `while` condition needs to keep you looping until the error gets below 0.01, which means that it needs to be `while abs((current xr-previous xr)/current xr) >= 0.01`

Comment: I agree with Robert.  You may want to add 2 more safeguards: -1- that the total number of iterations is less than some fixed constant (say 1000), and -2- that you never divide by zero (in case xr==0).  I updated the code accordingly (again, couldn't test as I have a floating license for MATLAB and all licenses are out).

Comment: @user91208 Ya that's a problem that converges on a result, I have tried your code but wondering why the loop din't function. The result of xr is just simmply (xl+xr)/2 and is not according to the converging condition

Comment: @user91208 Thanks a lot ya guys..really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to implement Step 3(c).

You also didn't "return to step 2" in steps 3(a) and 3(b) as the instructions state.  To do that, you will need to create a `while` loop as described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html); put in your while loop the condition that will keep it looping.  If that condition evaluates to false, it should drop out of the loop in accordance with step 3(c).

Use CONTINUE to fulfill the "Return to Step 2" part in steps 3(a) and 3(b); that moves execution back to the top of the loop.   See also [Jump command in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082605/jump-command-in-matlab)

Good luck.

Comment: I propose a `for` loop with fixed number of passes instead of `while` at least during debugging. Usually something goes wrong with my code and the `while` condition stays true for an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can put calculation in a function:

```
function f = some_function(x)
    R = 3;
    V = 30;
    f = (pi*R*x^2)-(pi*(x^3)/3)-V;
```

You can try with 100 passes (for safety):

```
for i=1:100
    xr_old = xr
    fr_old = fr

    xr = (xl+xu)/2;
    fr = some_function(xr);

    if abs((xr - xr_old)/xr) < MIN_STEP
        break
    end

    temp = fl*fr
    if temp < 0:
        xu = xr
        fu = fr
    else if temp > 0:
        xl = xr
        fl = fr
    end
end
```